# XQuery/XPath "except" operation - Select part of sequence that is not in other sequence

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a pretty simple example but I am just learning and can't find a solution for the following:

Given 2 sequences, being

```
<emp>10</emp>
<emp>42</emp>
<emp>100</emp>
```

and another sequence

```
  <emp>10</emp>
  <emp>42</emp>
```

Want i want to do is: Compare the sequences and return the part of sequences that is in the first, but not in the 2nd sequence, being `<emp>100</emp>` in this case.

I was thinking about an "except"-operation, but can't figure out how to make it working.

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `except` expression operates on node identity, not node value. What I think you want is a value comparison over your sequences. For example:

```
let $seq1 := 
  (<emp>10</emp>,
  <emp>42</emp>,
  <emp>100</emp>)
let $seq2 :=
  (<emp>10</emp>,
  <emp>42</emp>)
return $seq1[not(. = $seq2)]
```

=>
`<emp>100</emp>`

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot! Can you explain to me what the dot-operator (.) actually did here? In (. = $seq2)

Comment: Dot represents the context node - an essential XPath concept. When you apply a predicate to filter a node-set `NN[. = 'x']` then the context node is the node you are currently testing, i.e. it's effectively a range variable that ranges over the nodes in NN. The other important concept here is that '=' has existential semantics: AA=BB is true if any item in AA equals any item in BB. But I can't explain XPath concepts in 500 characters - you need to do some reading.